# External display not always working through HDMI on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.11.11

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hdmi, amdgpu, nvidia-prime

I have Lenovo Legion 5 with Ryzen R7 4800H, Vega iGPU, Nvidia 1650. The laptop faces many issues on Ubuntu from the beginning which forced me to use kernel 5.11.11. Somehow I managed to have both `amdgpu` and `nvidia` (driver 460) running and in `PRIME_profiles` I can choose among the options 'Nvidia', 'Nvidia on demand' and 'Intel iGPU' (should be AMD/Vega, must be a minor bug). However, I believe the hdmi port is directly connected to my Nvidia gpu.

Now when I choose Performence mode (Nvidia) in `PRIME_profiles`, everything works fine including the external display through HDMI port.
But when I choose `Nvidia on demand` or the iGPU the external display is not detected! For `Nvidia on demand`, I doubt the dedicated GPU is actually turned on ever!

```
xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0
```

throws error and

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

shows the iGPU (after showing the same error as above).
For comparison, in Windows in `Auto` GPU mode, the external display is always detected. Since I do not want to use Nvidia all the time to save the battery is there a way to get the external display detected on `Nvidia on demand` or, even better, on the iGPU mode?

More importantly, I am quite confused and have the following questions.

1. If the HDMI port is connected directly to dedicated GPU, can't we use it with iGPU? Is not this what windows is doing?
2. Does `Nvidia on demand` actually works on ubuntu 20.04?
3. The command `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0` is taken from Arch Linux I guess. Should it also work on Ubuntu?
4. And of course, since I do not want to use Nvidia all the time to save the battery is there a way to get the external display detected on `Nvidia on demand` or, even better, on the iGPU mode?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2. Do you think it's a kernel issue? How do I know if 5.11 is in testing phase? These later kernels (5.10 onward) solved (at least partially) a few key issues the laptop faced ubuntu. So I really do not want to give up 5.11.